# What kind of wax will prevent a bicycle chain from rusting after the bicycle is left in the rain?

Tags: chain, rust, wax

I left my bicycle out in the rain. When I try to pedal the bicycle, the chain locks up. That is to say, the roller chain got rusty after iron (ferrium), water and oxegen mixed together.

What kind of wax will ensure that a roller chain left out in the rain does not rust.

Comment: Any chain lube will prevent it... for a time.  Really though, anything will degrade and/or wash off eventually and require re-application.  What sort of time period are you thinking here?  Is it weeks on end, overnight, couple hours?

Comment: Do you actually mean wax, as in the stuff that sets to a solid? Or do you mean chain lube in general?

Comment: Uh, so you've already left your bike out and the chain already has rusted to the point of locking up? Then the question shouldn't be how to prevent it from rusting but what to do about the rust you've got. That's quite a different challenge, and definitely one that _wax_ is utterly unsuitable to solve.